# Iterate nested python dictionary efficiently

Tags: python, dictionary, flatten, dictionary-comprehension

I'm new to python. I have a nested dictionary like (k1,(t1,v1)). I would like to loop through each and every v1 values efficiently.

So lets say my dictionary  is my_dict. I want to access k , x, y with out two for loops efficiently, using a flattener or a dictionary comprehension. Please let me know the best practice.

```
     for k, v in my_dict.iteritems():
         inner_dict = my_dict.get(k)
         for x, y in inner_dict.iteritems():
             print(k, x , y )
```

Comment: A for loop is fine. What is a flattener?

Comment: You don't need `inner_dict = my_dict.get(k)`. You already have `v`.

Comment: Why use `inner_dict = my_dict.get(k)` if you could iterate over `v.iteritems()` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to loop over items if you're only interested in values:

```
flattened_values = (v for dct in my_dict.itervalues() for v in dct.itervalues())
for value in flattened_values:
    print(value)
```

**Edit**:

Based on your edit you do need the keys as well. In that case your code is fine apart from the redundant `inner_dict = my_dict.get(k)`, which is basically `v` only. A one-liner for the same would look like this:

```
for v in ((k1, k2, v2) for k1, v1 in my_dict.iteritems() for k2, v2 in v1.iteritems()):
    print(v)
```

Comment: Not sure if the `next(dct.itervalues())` should be considered "best practice".

Comment: IMO, I think the nested *for* version in the OP is still better, except they should use `.itervalues` in both loops.

Comment: @ashwini Chaudhary Actually i need all three information.. Key, Value1, Value2

Comment: @amateur That's not evident in your code. Could you please update it?